# Pop up keeps prompting for admin password on boot up

Tags: boot, apt, authentication

I keep getting a pop up requesting authentication with the following message:

```
Authentication is needed to run /usr/bin/apt as superuser
```

which if I am correct it sounds like `apt` is trying to do something in the background...

How do I find out what it is trying to do, and then prevent it from popping up every time I turn on my laptop... it is rather annoying but doesn't seem to be harming anything.

Thanks!

Comment: Check /var/log/syslog and /var/log/apt/history.log for clues.

Comment: This is the only thing I see from today 

Start-Date: 2020-12-10  07:53:13
Commandline: apt upgrade -y
Requested-By: joshua (1000)
Upgrade: vivaldi-snapshot:amd64 (3.5.2115.71-1, 3.5.2130.3-1), apt:amd64 (2.1.10, 2.1.10ubun>
End-Date: 2020-12-10  07:53:39

Comment: Does that match the popup time? If so, ask Joshua about whatever apt-related cron job or script they placed on your system.

Comment: I am Joshua, and I believe I figured it out....I have Apt-Update Indicator Gnome Extension and whenever the "Use a Custom command to check for updates" is enabled it prompts for the password...

Comment: Having just installed 20.04.1 from scratch, I was facing the same issue on boot up requesting keyring password. This only occurred after installing on-line accounts. I removed the online accounts and the keyring passwrod request has now ceased on boot up.